Why is there no case from $m = n$ in the contrapositive of the theorem, but in the normal form, does it exist?
Given this theorem:
If $m$ and $n$ are both perfect squares, then $nm$ is also a perfect square.
Contrapositive:
If $mn$ is not a perfect square, then at least $m$ or $n$ is not a perfect square.
I can't find an example for the contrapositive where $m = n$.
Reached the conclusion that is because any $m ^ 2$ is going to be a squared number.
Seeing that it is not specified that $m \neq n$, in the theorem, it makes sense but not in the contrapositive. I know that the contrapositive is equivalent, so it shouldn't have $m \neq n$.
So if the cases don't exist, does it mean it is not false, so it's true?
Also, the theorem is $f \to v$ for two numbers that are not squared.
E.g., $2 \cdot 3 = 6$, $6$ is squared; by conditional definition, it is true.
So, why is it not necessary to put the restriction $m \neq n$ in the contrapositive(is it because the example doesn't exist or related something to $f \to v$)?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Not sure what you are asking.  If $m=a^2, n=b^2$ then $mn=(ab)^2$.

In the contrapositive, the condition starts "If $mn$ is not a perfect square". That is never the case if $m=n$. But that does not affect the truth of the contrapositive statement, which still is true. (As is any conditional whose "if" statement is false.)

In other words, any $m=n$ is an example for the contrapositive statement to be (vacuously) true.

I'm asking about the contrapositive, it doesnt say that we cant have m = n. So I was trying to find a case where the contrapositive holds in that case. But couldn't find it.

This is very confusing.  Obviously there is no instance in which $m=n$ and yet $m\times n$ is not a perfect square.  Is that what you are asking?

From the comments:

I'm asking about the contrapositive, it doesnt say that we cant have m = n.

In the contrapositive, the assumption is that $mn$ is not a perfect square, which implies $m \ne n$.  So we cannot have $m = n$.


If $mn$ are not perfect square then at least $m$ or $n$ is not a perfect square.

Inside this theorem is an implication, $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ where
$P(m,n)$: $mn$ is not a perfect square.
$Q(m,n)$: At least one of $m$ or $n$ is not a perfect square.
The theorem states that $\forall m:\forall n: P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$.
An implication $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ can be true in three different ways:
$P(m,n)$ is true, $Q(m,n)$ is true, $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ is true.
$P(m,n)$ is false, $Q(m,n)$ is false, $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ is true.
$P(m,n)$ is false, $Q(m,n)$ is true, $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ is true.
We can combine the last two cases into one: $P(m,n)$ is false, $Q(m,n)$ is true or false (it doesn't matter which one), $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ is true.
So let's look at the cases:
Case $m = n$:
In this case $mn$ is a perfect square, so $P(m,n)$ is false.
Therefore $P(m,n) \implies Q(m,n)$ is true.
Case $m \neq n$:
Proceed with whatever proof you were going to do if you were told that $m \neq n$.
In short, the theorem doesn't need to say anything about $m=n$ or $m\neq n$ because the $m=n$ case is perfectly consistent with the theorem and it is trivial to prove this. You really only need to worry about the $m\neq n$ case.
